# Grabbing tensor indices with name of tensor attached

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to make an array out of specific components of a tensor.  I have found the wonderful command `np.argwhere()`. This returns the indices of the tensor meeting a specific criteria, however it does not name them as components of the tensor, i.e. they come back as `[0,0,1,1]` versus `x[0,0,1,1]` for a tensor `x`.

Is there a built in or slick way to grab the components of a tensor that meet a certain criteria where the components are written with their indices and the name of the tensor attached?

Comment: What exactly are you after with `x[0, 0, 1, 1]`? The value held in your tensor `x` at position with indices `[0, 0, 1, 1]'? Or a string representation of `x[0, 0, 1, 1]`?

Comment: @Jaime Thats right, the value for that particular component.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `where` instead of `argwhere`...

```
>>> x = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
>>> x
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> np.argwhere(x > 1)
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2]])
>>> np.where(x > 1)
(array([0, 1, 1, 1]), array([2, 0, 1, 2]))
>>> x[np.where(x > 1)]
array([2, 3, 4, 5])
```